# Switching from hash-based nav to HTML5 History API

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-history

I'm trying to figure out how to use the History API for my webpage. Currently, it's a simple page where the navbar toggles content visibility on click by changing an ID's `display` to `none` or `block`.

I'd like to switch over to the History API because of the browser back button memory, but all of the examples I'm finding use AJAX to load data from a separate file on click. My pages aren't big enough to warrant asynchronous loading.

Is there any way for regular URLs to trigger CSS property changes the way that hashes do?

Comment: "I'd like to switch over to the History API because of the browser back button memory" Aren't hash changes recorded in the browser history too?

Comment: what CSS property changes are you speaking of?

Comment: @BoltClock Does the back button still work with hashes? I didn't know that. I can look into it.

Comment: @dandavis Currently I'm showing/hiding content by changing `display: none` to `display: block` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

No, CSS can only react to `:target` via the hash component of the URL. However you can still take advantage of the History API if you want to; you'll just need a little bit of additional javascript. For example you could a `data-target` attribute to the `<html>` element which changes depending on the URL, and your css could then react to this through something like:

```
[data-target="home"] #home-page { display: block; }
```

The History API allows you to store some state with each entry, so you could use this to store the target identifier and then retrieve this again in your "popstate" handler - e.g.

```
history.pushState({ target: 'home' }, '', '/home')
document.documentElement.dataset.target = 'home'
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (e) {
  document.documentElement.dataset.target = e.state.target
})
```